# Can't downgrade from Windows 10 Pro for Workstations after testing provision key

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I installed a fresh copy of Windows and upgraded the "edition" by using a Windows 10 Pro for Workstations provision key to test the stability of various features. I have been able to do this in the past on an already activated copy of Windows 10 Pro and could revert by re-entering my Windows 10 pro key. This is the only way to test the stability of ReFS features, as they were removed from Windows 10 Pro in version 1709.

The difference this time is that I did not pre-activate a Windows 10 Pro key. Now I am unable to complete the activation with any of my Windows 10 Pro keys, as activation fails and says that the key is not valid for this product.

I have tried to manually remove the existing product key without success:

```
slmgr /upk
slmgr /cpky
slmgr /rearm
```

I have already finished configuring and updating Windows, as well as installing all of my software. Is there no way to revert this change?

Comment: Are those keys retail or OEM?

Comment: My keys are all retail and activate normally. This is the first time I tried testing with a Windows 10 Pro for Workstations provision key *before* activating Windows 10 Pro with a retail key.

Comment: You shouldn't have to activate Windows 10 Professional in order to upgrade a Windows 10 Professional installation to Windows 10 Professional for Workstation.  Why didn't you just not install `Windows 10 Professional for Workstation`? So do you have `Windows 10 Professional for Workstation` installed or are you trying to upgrade `Windows 10 Professional` to `Windows 10 Professional for Workstation`? I realize my train of thought might seem to be all over the place but that's partially due to the description you have provided.

Comment: There is no separate installation media for Windows 10 Professional for Workstation. The only gate for the different feature set is the product key. I wanted to use the provision key to validate the current state of ReFS before using my retail key. But this appears to have locked me out of using my non-Workstation key. I did not have this issue previously when using the provision key ontop of an already activated copy of Windows.

Comment: @Zhro - “ There is no separate installation media for Windows 10 Professional for Workstation.” - You can create one. What exactly is the provisioned key? Are you talking about the generic key that is well documented?

Comment: Yes. This is the provision key which is supposed to be used temporarily before activating over KMS. I was using it to activate the Workstation feature to test ReFS, which was removed from the standard Professional edition.

Comment: Just to confirm, you upgraded to Windows 10 Professional for Workstation, using the generic KMS license key, but you only have a retail Windows 10 Professional license key.  So what’s the contents of *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion*?

Comment: [Here](https://uupdump.net/download.php?id=035d3119-ab89-4771-8dea-8f291986630b&pack=en-us&edition=professional) is how you create a Professional for Workstations ISO